# What exactly does the internet of things encompass?

Tags: definitions

When I think of the Internet of things, I think of fairly low bandwidth devices connected to the internet.

That could be automotive telematics, medical devices, building monitoring, factory sensors, etc.

However, I was just thinking of smartphones in terms of internet of things and had to correct myself... or did I?
Can a smartphone be regarded as part of a subset of the internet of things?

Is there a good definition that something segregates connected computers from IoT and states what exactly IoT encompasses?

Comment: Hi @SeanJ, do the linked duplicates answer this? If not, do feel free to edit and clarify what we can help with.

Comment: @aurora0001 yes, it's slightly different but much the same! S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are a part of the Internet of Things (IoT). Smartphones can be interconnected in the IoT with other objects. Besides, They are Smart Objects [1]. They can obtain data using their sensor, they can activate things or do actions, and they can process the information.

Smart Object Definition [1]: Any electronic device that can be connected to the Internet and collect data, like a sensor, or perform an action in an object, normally called actuator.

IoT Definition: 'The Internet of Things is the interconnection of heterogeneous objects through the Internet' [2].

[1] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307638707_A_review_about_Smart_Objects_Sensors_and_Actuators
[2] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260252345_Midgar_Generation_of_heterogeneous_objects_interconnecting_applications_A_Domain_Specific_Language_proposal_for_Internet_of_Things_scenarios